# Unable to locate list elements using Nightwatch

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, nightwatch.js, assertions

I have some list elements:

```
< button id={"productBook"} className="fito-btn fito-btn-long" style={this.props.styles.btnBrandRevers} onClick={this.props.onOfferSelect.bind(null, product)}>
 < FormattedMessage id='app.Book' defaultMessage='Book' />
< /button>
```

When asserting the element with id `productBook` as:

```
.assert.visible('button[id=productBook]')
```

I'm getting an error:

```
Testing if element <button[id=productBook]> is visible. Element could not be located. - expected "true" but got: "null"
```

I don't understand why this doesn't work for this specific element while it works for other elements. Is there some different way that list elements need to be verified?
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the shorthand `#` for id:

```
assert.visible('button#productBook')
```

or

```
assert.visible('#productBook')
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the HTML you have shared the **id** attribute of the `<button>` is dynamically generated. So you may not be able to **assert** through **id**. Instead you can *assert* the *visibility* of the **FormattedMessage** through the following *Locator Strategy* :

- `xpath` :

  ```
  //button[@class='fito-btn fito-btn-long']/FormattedMessage[@id=\"app.Book\"][@defaultMessage='Book']
  ```

Comment: But this will locate both the buttons. I just need to specifically locate one of them and click on it, for example the second one.

Comment: Both??? Of-coarse `<FormattedMessage id='app.Book' defaultMessage='Book' />` is a child node of `<button id={"productBook"} ... > ..... </button>`. You won't be able to click the _Parent Node_ alone.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't recognize any elements, don't understand why this is. However, the elements are within a list with the same selectors. So I am sure this won't work and I will have to do it some other way to get the n-th child of the list

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

`.assert.not.elementPresent('tr[...]')`